# MySQL connection, infinite PHP loops and temporary outages

Tags: php, mysql, loops, connection

I have a PHP script that is, by design, an infinite loop. Inside the loop are various mysql queries.

Before it enters the loop it connects to the database like this:

```
include(database.php)

while (1)
{
  try {
    $q = $db->prepare('SELECT * from stuff');
    ......
   }
   catch (PDOException $err)
   {
     return $err
   }
}
```

Whenever I have to restart the mysql server for whatever reason, the php loop throws errors about not being able to connect to the database as expected. However when the MySQL server is back online again the PHP script continues to throw errors about the connection until kill the script loop and start the script again.

Is the reason something to do with the database connection code being outside of the loop?

Comment: YES, that woudl befinitely be a problem.

Comment: In your `catch` block you really should be doing a check for specific errors that you believe you can recover from. If its not one of those then you should exit. Potentially in this case you could code some sort of `sleep` and try again loop.

Comment: Just create a new connection in the catch block.

Comment: So I'm best checking if the error caught is a connection error, and if so re-include the database config? It seems a little weird that one connection error can kill all future connection attempts, but hey ho.

Answer (score 0):

WHILE 1 is an infinite loop,so it tries that select even after Mysql shutdown and when you restart it it doesn't reconnect automatically.